# How to add has_many associations to record on create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following Rails models:

```rb
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :project_managers, length: { minimum: 1, message: "Please assign at least one PM" }
  has_many :project_assignments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :project_managers, through: :project_assignments, source: :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_assignments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :projects, through: :project_assignments
end

class ProjectAssignment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now I'm trying to add project managers while creating the record:

```rb
  Project.create!(title: "foobar", project_manager_ids: [1])
```

But this leads too `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Project assignments is invalid`
Is there a way to add project managers directly on create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project model, add the following

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_assignments, allow_destroy: true
```

In your Project controller, in strong params add the following

```
def params
  params.require(:project).permit(
    :id,
    :title,
    project_assignments_attributes: [
      :id,
      :user_id,
      _destroy
    ]
  )
end
```

Comment: But how do I write the `create!` function? How do I set the IDs there?

Comment: ```Project.create!(title: "foo Bar", project_assigments_attributes: [ { user_id: 1}])```

Comment: Great, thanks! `Project.create!(title: "blabla", customer_id: 1, project_assignments_attributes: [{user_id:1}])` works fine, but when I run `Project.findy(757).update!(title: "blablaaaaaa", customer_id: 1, project_assignments_attributes: [{user_id:1}])` it creates a second `ProjectAssignment`. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: on update you need to send the id of project assignments attributes  ```Project.find(757).update!(title: "blablaaaaaa", customer_id: 1, project_assignments_attributes: [{id: 'id of project assignment', user_id:1}]) ```

Comment: Hmmmmm okay. But passing an empty array to destroy all related ProjectAssignments isn‘t possible, isn‘t it?

Comment: if you want to delete from project assignment attributes, you need to send the following ```Project.find(757).update!(title: "blablaaaaaa", customer_id: 1, project_assignments_attributes: [{id: 'id of project assignment', _destroy: 1}])``` it deletes only that particular assignment

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I thought that it would be possible to always send the full list of assignments in the update method, so that an empty array would delete all the current assignments automatically. But I'm going to add some own logic for this :-)